# Combo-box not expanding

Tags: extjs, combobox

I am creating a multiselect combobox(extjs 6.0.1 version). A textbox has been embedded in it. On clicking in the textbox the combobox collapses.The same issue was happening for select all checkbox but it worked fine after using combo.expand().Also on clicking the Deselect all, the scrollbar goes to the end. This works fine in extjs version 4.1.1 Fiddle below 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1kn2

Answer (score 0):

Why adding a text field in the first place?
Shouldn't suffice a normal extjs combo box with editable set to true?
http://docs.sencha.com/ext/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html

Comment: You are correct but my requirement is a separate textfield

Comment: Ok, but it seems the behavior is intended. If you click on the textfield the combo box looses focus. It's dirty but you could try to put an listener on the textfield that keeps the combo box open.

Comment: @MarcRambow You shared a comboBox link. What config I need to check. I understand you don't have enough reputation but please comment in answer. Your answer is not at all leading towards the answer of specific question.

Comment: @UDID if you telling me what you want to know I could help. The needed config for a editable combo box is in my answer.

Comment: @MarcRambow ya got it. I assumed the same

Comment: I would guess that the event is  bubbling to the parent element. You could try to look into the event chain. Could you add the listener to the fiddle?